# Use Properties File from IBM WAS server in GWT Project

Tags: java, gwt, ant

We have a GWT project written in java. We have a logout URL that is specific to environment (https://example-dev.net/logoff.htm, https://example-sit.net/logoff.htm, ...). This works fine when we add this property from a properties file that is packaged inside our project/src folder like the following:

com.example.shared.constants/LogoutUrl.java

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Constants;

public interface LogoutUrl extends Constants {
    String LOGOUT_URL();
}
```

com.example.shared.constants/LogoutUrl.properties

```
LOGOUT_URL = https://example-env.net/logoff.htm
```

This does not look like a good practice, as this needs the URL change and new war creation in each server. I tried adding this properties file on server (IBM WAS) and retrieve it from the code using java.util.Properties. But GWT build is failing in this case. We are using ant build. Please suggest a way to segregate this properties file from our project and retrieve from server.

Update:
Adding the part how I tried to configure using an external properties file that we added in app server:

```
InputStream inputStream  = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logouturl.properties");
                            Properties prop = new Properties();
                            try {
                                prop.load(inputStream);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                //LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while loading logouturl.properties file.", e);
                            }
                            String logoutUrl = prop.get("LOGOUT_URL").toString();
                            Window.Location.replace(logoutUrl);
```

But gwtc build is failing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You're using GWT's i18 internationalization support Constants mechanism for what it sounds like shouldn't be treated as a constant in your application, but instead a configurable value which may differ per server/environment. This seems incompatible. The i18 Constants mechanism is for "constants", which can differ based on locale. What it sounds like you're looking for is a way to provide configurable values for your logout URL, which has little to do with i18, or "constants".

You can dynamically configure your logout URL by using a JNDI variable for your app server, or by having it reference an external .properties file (one that doesn't need to be tied to a i18 Constants class).

Comment: I configured using an external properties file that we added on the app server. I updated my question with how I added that properties file in my code. But gwtc build is failing.

Comment: If the Java code you've pasted is part of your GWT module, it should fail. Note that GWT java code is just java code that gets compiled into javascript. Not all Java code can get compiled into javascript, and GWT explains in documentation that there is only a subset of Oracle's Java libraries that can be used in GWT, so that it compiles into Javascript (packages like java.util.*, java.lang.*, etc). I don't think InputStream is part of that subset -- [Compatibility with the Java Language and Libraries](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasics.html)

Comment: Are you sending any data form the server to your client side GWT code already? Are you using GWT's RPC mechanism to do this? If so, can you use that mechanism to send the configured logout URL value as needed? We do something similar in a project I'm working on. We have configuration on the server, that varies per environment. Some of that configuration is sent to the Client side GWT module when the user logs in to our app.